# What are the chances for an H4 international masters student to get a teaching job at a US community college?

Tags: teaching, united-states, job, community-college

I have a B.E Civil Engineering and M.tech Environmental Engineering degree from India. Also I have 2 years of teaching experience in an Engineering college in India. Currently I am residing in US. Is it possible for me to get a teaching job in community colleges? How should I prepare myself to get a teaching job here?

To clarify: I have an H4 visa.

Comment: Do you already have legal authorization to work in the US?  Community colleges may be less willing to sponsor you for an employment visa.

Comment: No. I am in H4 visa now. Can you please suggest some options for me?

Answer (score 8):

You clarified that you have an H4 visa. As you know, you are not normally permitted to work under an H4 visa. Even unpaid tutoring might be considered a violation of the H4 terms. So you would need to first change your visa status by either:

- Applying for a green card
- Getting your own H1B or other work visa

As far as getting your own H1, unless you are located in a place where there is an absolute dearth of available faculty, I think it highly unlikely that a community college will sponsor a work visa for you. The amount of paperwork that needs to be done is tremendous (the Department of Labor certification itself is an inch thick)-- as well as the filing costs and attorney's fees. They may also have no experience doing this, unlike the international scholar's office at a larger institution. Finally, many CC faculty are part-time so you may not even qualify for a H1B to begin with.

I would ask your spouse to apply for permanent residency for the both of you and then go on the job market once you have employment authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If you are legally permitted to work in the U.S., this should be possible.  Please don't expect a lot, salary-wise.  But it can be a rewarding job.

Obviously, your previous teaching experience is a plus.  If your English is easy for U.S. students to understand, and you are patient about any communication challenges that might arise, that would be another plus.

If there is no full-time opening in your area at present, you could try teaching one or two classes as an adjunct.  This can help you get a foot in the door.